# EJB Remote Interface in Client App

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I am starting with EJB and I am having a problem:

I am guided by this tut on youtube - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xJx9hpzkbs
(It's in french but it doesn't really matter)

So basically what tut (And me as well) does is, create an EJB project, create stateless Session Bean (MyBean) and a Remote Interface (MyBeanRemote), with one simple method returning a string.

He also creates dynamic web project and uses the following code in a Servlets doGet method to call a bean method:

```
Context con = new InitialContext();
Object ob = con.lookup("MyBean/remote");

if(ob != null){
    MyBeanRemote bean = (MyBeanRemote) ob;
    // And then prints out the returned value from the method
}
```

But the problem is that I have no MyBeanRemote interface avaliable in the client project. how does he get it? (5:17 on Video)

Comment: Include jar containing interfaces in client project.

Comment: yes I got it, but how does the author of the video reference the interface? he doesn't include any jars

Comment: I haven't visited tutorial link, but I guess that EJB & client application are part of an EAR or has illustrated through single application.

Answer (score 0):

tIf yours is a maven based project, you can generate client jar by adding a plugin to your pom.xml file as below

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                <clientIncludes>
                    <clientInclude>**/*Local.class</clientInclude>
                    <clientInclude>**/*Remote.class</clientInclude>
                    <clientInclude>**/*Exception.class</clientInclude>
                </clientIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at the 2:47min he deploys the EJB (interface included) in the server. So you have NO to add it explicitly to the project (that is the idea of a **remote** bean). So you only needs to know the name's interface ("MyBean/remote") to do the lookup. Then the container will resolve and find the correct object that is implementing that interface.

This is a way to use the EJB, you could see later that you can use a local interface, and even a no interface-view for you beans. Maybe you are thinking "remote to what?, local to what?" well... to the JVM (usually). You can still make a remote call (as the JVM with the EJB's exists in other server) to a EJB in the same JVM, this has a higher cost that a local/no-interface call.

This basic concept is then used commonly as: **Dependency Injection**, where you only describe the interface's object (plus @EJB annotation) and the container will figure out the proper object.

To know more about when choose local vs remote, please refer to this article:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html